# Is there a known representation for this set derived from a Lie group $\subseteq \text{SU}(n)$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G \subseteq \text{SU}(n)$ be a Lie group for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with a proper Lie subgroup $H \subset G$ having Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ such that $H = e^{\mathfrak{h}}$. Let $g_0 \in G$ be an element of $G$.

I know that $\mathfrak{h}$ constitutes a linear subspace of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$, and hence is represented by a vector space spanned by skew-Hermitian matrices. Hence let $\{b_i\}_{i = 1}^{m}$ be a basis for $\mathfrak{h}$, where each $b_i$ is an order-$n$ skew-Hermitian matrix.

Now, consider the set $$H' = g_0H=\{g_0h\;|\;h \in H\}.$$ If $g_0 \notin H$, this cannot be a Lie group since it doesn't contain the identity, however it is clearly a differentiable manifold $\subseteq \text{SU}(n)$.

My question is: Is there a special name for such a set? Does it have an associated algebra (not a Lie algebra, but some equivalent with a matrix representation)? In particular, is the algebra representable by some linear or linear-affine space whose basis can be computed in a straightforward way from $\{b_i\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you consider is commonly called a left coset of $H$ in $G$ (which is standard language in group theory). In a Lie group, such a left coset is a submanifold which is diffeomorphic to $H$ (with the diffeomorphism given by left multiplication by $g_0$). Moreover, you can make that space of all left cosets into a smooth manifold, which is exactly the homogeneous space $G/H$. This comes with a smooth projection $p:G\to G/H$ whose fibers (i.e. the pre-images of points) are exactly the left cosets.

I don't think that there is something like an algebra associated to it. Indeed in each point of a coset that tangent space to the coset consists exactly of the values of the left invariant vector fields $L_X$ with $X\in\mathfrak h$, the Lie algebra of $H$. So the corresponding subspace of $\mathfrak g$ is $\mathfrak h$ itself.

Comment: I understand. I was hoping something more might be known about manifolds with this particular property, but I thank you all the same for your insights and for clarifying the terminology.